Gstreamer vp8 use of temporal layer not working
I am trying to run gstreamer vp8 rtp stream, and temporal layers need to be used do to switch video quality on sfu side. But looks like parameters not supported. Can someone help or at least point me to right direction please.
Dummy attempt and log.
Command:
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! vp8enc temporal-scalability-number-layers=3 ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

Log:
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.142203811 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN                  vpxenc gstvpxenc.c:1832:gst_vpx_enc_set_format:<vp8enc0> error: Failed to initialize encoder
0:00:00.142234257 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN                  vpxenc gstvpxenc.c:1832:gst_vpx_enc_set_format:<vp8enc0> error: invalid parameter
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVP8Enc:vp8enc0: Failed to initialize encoder
Additional debug info:
../ext/vpx/gstvpxenc.c(1832): gst_vpx_enc_set_format (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVP8Enc:vp8enc0:
invalid parameter
Execution ended after 0:00:00.001366847
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
0:00:00.142428062 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN            videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:771:gst_video_encoder_setcaps:<vp8enc0> rejected caps video/x-raw, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)10/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)2:4:5:1
0:00:00.142468288 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4361:gst_pad_peer_query:<videoconvert0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:00.142624718 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4361:gst_pad_peer_query:<v4l2src0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:00.142650650 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4450:gst_v4l2_object_set_crop:<v4l2src0:src> VIDIOC_S_CROP failed
0:00:00.143887741 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:3274:gst_v4l2_object_reset_compose_region:<v4l2src0:src> Failed to get default compose rectangle with VIDIOC_G_SELECTION: Invalid argument
0:00:00.145041960 511337 0x75f820000b70 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:848:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> Uncertain or not enough buffers, enabling copy threshold
Freeing pipeline ...

More complex attempts
Command:
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! vp8enc temporal-scalability-number-layers=3 temporal-scalability-periodicity=4 temporal-scalability-layer-id="1,2,3" temporal-scalability-layer-sync-flags="false,false,false,true" temporal-scalability-rate-decimator="1,2,4" temporal-scalability-target-bitrate="500000,1000000,1500000" ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

Log
(gst-launch-1.0:511720): GStreamer-WARNING **: 11:06:28.793: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented
0:00:00.015960004 511720 0x5df725548210 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:612:gst_parse_element_make: could not set property "temporal-scalability-layer-id" in element "vp8enc" to "1,2,3"
0:00:00.015979772 511720 0x5df725548210 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:1264:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no sink [source=@0x5df725537c30]
0:00:00.017086009 511720 0x5df725548210 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:1264:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@0x5df72554e290]
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "temporal-scalability-layer-id" in element "vp8enc" to "1,2,3"

At the last attempt I stuck at the part how can I pass GArray of gint in command line.
Also the docs on gstreamer vp8enc, the part about temporal layers:
  temporal-scalability-layer-flags: Sequence defining coding layer flags
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Default: "<  >"
                        GstValueArray of GValues of type "GstVPXEncTsLayerFlags"
  temporal-scalability-layer-id: Sequence defining coding layer membership
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Array of GValues of type "gint"
  temporal-scalability-layer-sync-flags: Sequence defining coding layer sync flags
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Default: "<  >"
                        GstValueArray of GValues of type "gboolean"
  temporal-scalability-number-layers: Number of coding layers to use
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 1 - 5 Default: 1 
  temporal-scalability-periodicity: Length of sequence that defines layer membership periodicity
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 16 Default: 0 
  temporal-scalability-rate-decimator: Rate decimation factors for each layer
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Array of GValues of type "gint"
  temporal-scalability-target-bitrate: Target bitrates (bits/sec) for coding layers (one per layer)
                        flags: readable, writable


Array notation is {1,2,3} (do put it in quotes as it becomes a string).

@FlorianZwoch At least error has changed.
(gst-launch-1.0:110035): GStreamer-WARNING **: 10:24:12.898: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented
0:00:00.008691653 110035 0x64737587c820 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:612:gst_parse_element_make: could not set property "temporal-scalability-layer-id" in element "vp8enc" to "1"

